# VUE Change body background color for some pages

Tags: vue.js

I would need to change the body background color for some pages in my application.

In detail, the default body background color is white, when I land in the page A i would the body background color change in red for example and when I land in the page B I would it change in white again and when I land in page C it change in blue.

So DEFAULT(white) -> A(red) -> B(white) -> C(blue) and so on.

I found only this solution using javascript and the created and beforeUnmount vue methods:

```
  created() {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
  },

  beforeUnmount() {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
  },
```

It works properly but it seems to me too cumbersome because i have to restore the default beheviour manually every time i unmount the component and I change the screen, for example if i don't restore in the screen A the background color to white it remains rightly red

There is another way maybe already thought by the creators of vue to do this in simple way?

Thank you very much

BR

Comment: There are lots of different ways to approach this! Are you using state management like vuex or pinia, or vue router?

Comment: if your app is full screen you can do it in vue instead, and change the background color of your App component instead of the body, and then it will be reactive, you can have a computed property that will get updated by vue

Comment: Hi @JonathanBowman yes i use both vuex and vue router in my application, could you provide me an example in this way please? thank you

Comment: Hi @Lk77 I did't understand this solution could you provide me and example please? thank you

Comment: Well you have an App component, you could put your background color here, on the first div of the App component, using :style=""

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using the router, you could have something like this in your App.vue on the main element, or whichever element you want (obligatory "code untested", since I'm on an airplane right now):

```
// App.vue    

<v-app :style="`background-color: ${$route.meta.color || #ffffff};`">
    ...
</v-app>
```

And in your routes file is where you can set that, under the meta key:

```
// router/routes.js
{
    path: '/',
    name: 'dashboard',
    meta: {
        color: #f1f1f1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I see you use v-app tag in App.vue and it is a Vuetify tag, i don't use it in the project.

My App.vue file contains this:

<template>
  <router-view></router-view>
</template>